# Ternary Operator not working in godaddy php (parsererror)

Tags: php, codeigniter, ternary-operator

`<br />↵<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected ':' in <b>.../ajax.php</b> on line <b>87</b>`

LINE 87: `$conditions = ($this->input->post()) ? : array('tutor'=>$this->session->userdata('user_id'));`

line 87 works fine on localhost, but when I use godaddy I get that error. Is there something I need to set in php.ini or something to get Ternary operators to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ternary operator (as the name suggests) usually expects 3 arguments

```
$var = $expr ? $trueValue : $falseValue;
```

With PHP5.3 its allowed to omit `$trueValue`. In this case its `$expr` is used for it

```
$var = $expr ? : $falseValue;
// same as
$var = $expr ? $expr : $falseValue;
```

You probably don't have PHP5.3 on your server. As you can see in my example its quite easy to fix this and make it ready for pre-5.3

```
$conditions = ($this->input->post()) 
            ? ($this->input->post()) 
            : array('tutor'=>$this->session->userdata('user_id'));
```

Comment: wow thanks! thats still a lot shorter than writing out the if statements fully. I guess i'll just have to use the pre-5.3 method..

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `? :` you are using is PHP 5.3 only.

Set a default value:

```
$conditions = ($this->input->post()) ? $this->input->post() : array('tutor'=>$this->session->userdata('user_id'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6418864) is correct, but misses one important point:

```
$x = $a ? : $b; // valid in PHP 5.3
```

should indeed be replaced with

```
$x = $a ? $a : $b; // valid in older versions of PHP
```

However, when you're dealing with functions, not variables, be aware of side-effects:

```
$conditions = ($this->input->post()) 
        ? ($this->input->post()) 
        : array('tutor'=>$this->session->userdata('user_id'));
```

In the above case, if `$this->input->post()`returns a truthy value, the function will be executed again, which may not be what you want. You can see this more clearly by expanding the ternary operator to its full form:

```
if ($this->input->post()) {
    $conditions = $this->input->post();
} else {
    $conditions = array('tutor' => $this->session->userdata('user_id'));
}
```

You can see that the function is executed on lines one **and** two above. If you don't want that, try this instead:

```
if (!$conditions = $this->input->post()) {
    // Single equal sign in an if condition: make assignment, and check
    // whether the result is truthy.
    $conditions = array('tutor' => $this->session->userdata('user_id'));
}
```

This is a fairly common pattern in my own code. This will execute the function `$this->input->post()` only once. If the result is truthy, that result is stored in `$conditions`. If the result is not truthy, the code inside the `if` condition is run. This assigns the fallback value to `$conditions`. The benefit is that, in either case, `$this->input->post()` is run only once.